# Delete Memory allocated in another function?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, delete-operator

So I just finished my implementation of merge sort but it occurred to me that I didn't delete the memory returned from recursive calls that I was discarding, so I added delete statements for array1 and array2, and then suddenly my merge sort doesn't work.....Why does adding the delete statements near the end of my function screw everything up? Do I need to free the memory?

The code is below:

```
/**
 * Runs merge sort on this ArrayList<T>. Interface function to the central,
 * recursive, merge sort function.
 */
template<class T>
void ArrayList<T>::mergeSort() {

    T* temp = mergeSort(array, size);
    delete [] array;
    array = temp;
}

/**
 * Runs merge sort on the passed in array. Recursive.
 *
 * @param array the array to sort.
 * @param arraySize the size of the array that is to be sorted.
 * @return the sorted array.
 */
template<class T>
T* ArrayList<T>::mergeSort(T* array, int arraySize) {

    T* returnArray = array;

    //If the array is more than one element.
    if (arraySize > 1) {

        int size1 = arraySize / 2;
        int size2 = arraySize - size1;

        T* array1;
        T* array2;

        //Recurse.
        array1 = mergeSort(array, size1);
        array2 = mergeSort(array + size1, size2);

        returnArray = new T[arraySize];

        //Loop through all elements in returnArray.
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        while (i < arraySize) {

            //Place the lesser of two elements in returnArray.
            if ((array1[j] <= array2[k] && j < size1)
                    || k == size2) {

                returnArray[i] = array1[j];
                j++;
            }
            else {

            returnArray[i] = array2[k];
                k++;
            }

            i++;
        }
```

/---THESE ARE THE DELETES IN QUESTION!!-----/

```
        delete [] array1;
        delete [] array2;
    }

    return returnArray;
}
```

Comment: When you say "suddenly my merge sort doesn't work," what do you mean? Does it crash? Does it produce incorrect results? Something else? You need to be more specific and tell us any specific error messages you're seeing.

Comment: No specific error was given, I run it, it crashes...pretty sudden ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i see a problem when array size is equal to 2
since you call

```
array1 = mergeSort(array, size1);
array2 = mergeSort(array + size1, size2);
```

and size1=1,size2=1
then both of these calls will return and you will have the following values in the variables

```
array1 = array;
array2 = array+1;
```

and array2 isn't an allocated memory address so deleting it should fail with an error or do something undefined so i would suggest fixing that before you continue

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked in full detail but one thing springs to mind: when `mergeSort` is called with an array whose size is `<= 1` it returns the passed array without allocating a new one but upon returning from the recursive call you will attempt to delete it anyway. You could improve your code by adding:

```
if (size1 > 1)
   delete [] array1;
if (size2 > 1)
   delete [] array2;
```